# Can we use sum types in haskell FFI?

Tags: haskell, ffi

https://wiki.haskell.org/Foreign_Function_Interface#Data_structures

The document above only describes the case that only one data constructor is involved.
I'm looking for a method to define sum types and perform pattern matching on them within Haskell FFI.
I'd like to avoid additional serialization/deserialization overheads. From my understanding, FFI with a single data constructor described in the document above does not require serialization/deserialization overheads.
Is this achievable?

Additionally, it would be really great if we can apply custom pattern matching logic to foreign values.
Consider a situation where you have a Rust function returning Option<&U>, and you wish to pattern match it in Haskell.
Rust employs null pointer optimization. There is no such thing corresponding to a tag in the `Option<&U>` value.
Nevertheless, I want to handle the foreign value in a Haskell-like way, such as:

```hs
case rustPointer of
  Nothing -> ...
  Just u -> ...
```

Hence, it seems that we need a way to define custom pattern match logic for foreign values to achieve this.
Is there a mechanism available to accomplish this?

Comment: "From my understanding, FFI with a single data constructor described in the document above does not require serialization/deserialization overheads" -- no. The `Storable` instance gives the serialization/deserialization.

Comment: Is there no method in haskell to utilize foreign data without copying it then?

Comment: You can always pass opaque pointers back and forth across the FFI boundary at no serialization cost (receiving a `Ptr` if the foreign object is opaque to Haskell code, or sending a `StablePtr` if the Haskell object is opaque to foreign code). The tradeoff is that any operations you want to do must be implemented in the language that has non-opaque access, and so those operations will incur an FFI-boundary-crossing cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully it comes as no surprise to you that GHC does not support treating arbitrarily structured in-memory foreign data as first class Haskell data types.  That is, there's no way you can take, say, a Rust `Option<&U>` whose in-memory representation is a null pointer for `None` and a non-null pointer for `Some` and expect to treat it natively in Haskell code as a `Maybe (Ptr U)` much less as `Maybe U`.  I'm not aware of any general use programming languages that support this sort of flexibility.  (Even C can't *really* do this, it just imposes structure at a lower level than most other languages -- think endianness, or non-IEEE floating point representations.)

So, you have two choices.  First, you can "fake" the GHC data structures on the foreign side by presenting GHC with an in-memory data structure that passes as a native structure.  This is tremendously error prone and dangerous, as there's no official, supported API for doing this.  Obviously, if the foreign data structure is not already in the form of "fake" GHC data, then you need to marshal it anyway: you'll just be doing that in foreign code instead of in Haskell code.  So, if you want to avoid marshalling overhead entirely, you'll have to make the fake GHC data structures the "native" representation in your foreign code, and do all your foreign processing on what are ultimately GHC native values.  This might be doable in C or Rust, but you'll be writing a lot of awkward code!

For curiosity's sake, I tried getting this to work.  Constructing a GHC-native representation of a `Just 2.0 :: Maybe Double` in C for example looks something like this.  It involves returning a pointer to a two-word closure that consists of a pointer to the `Just` info block and a payload that in turn consists of a pointer to a two-word closure that consists of a pointer to the `D#` info block (constructor for boxed `Double`s) and a payload of the actual `double`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

extern char base_GHCziMaybe_Just_con_info[];
extern char ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Dzh_con_info[];

typedef struct con_s {
        void *info;
        void *payload[0];
} con_t;

con_t
*justTwo(void)
{
        union {
                double d;
                long l;
        } u;

        con_t *just = malloc(sizeof(con_t)+sizeof(void*));
        con_t *two = malloc(sizeof(con_t)+sizeof(void*));
        just->info = base_GHCziMaybe_Just_con_info;
        just->payload[0] = two;
        two->info = ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Dzh_con_info;
        u.d = 2.0;
        two->payload[0] = (void*) u.l;
        return just;
}
```

You can then access this value in Haskell code using something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CApiFFI #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UnboxedTuples #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}

module Main (main) where

import GHC.Exts

foreign import capi unsafe "two.c justTwo" c_justTwo :: IO (Ptr ())

main :: IO ()
main = do
  two <- c_justTwo
  print $ case two of Ptr a -> case addrToAny# a of (# v #) -> (v :: Double)
```

Incredibly, this seems to work.  I got it to compile and print `Just 2.0` and the resulting assembly genuinely treats the foreign pointer as a native GHC object without any marshalling "overhead".  It's unclear to me how this would interact with garbage collection, though.  It seemed to work okay in my testing, but I wouldn't exactly be shocked if such a program randomly crashed now and then.

Of course, if marshalling "overhead" is actually significant enough to cause you concern, you basically have to turn the garbage collector off.  A single major garbage collection in a medium sized Haskell program is likely the equivalent of marshalling tens if not hundreds of thousands of values.

In any event, I assume you'd agree that this isn't really a viable approach.

The second alternative is to give up on trying to use foreign representations as first class Haskell types and instead rely on second class mechanisms in Haskell to access the foreign representations.  To take the Rust `Option` pointer as an example, if you have a foreign function that returns such a pointer:

```
newtype RustPtr a = RustPtr (Ptr a)
foreign import capi unsafe "option.c getOption" getOption :: IO (RustPtr Double)
```

you can call the function:

```
p <- getOption
```

and pass around the `p :: RustPtr Double` without any marshalling, except to the extent that it's already been marshalled into a boxed `Ptr` by copying the return value from the C `getOption` function into a two-word GHC heap object.  At the point of use where you want to dispatch on this pointer like a `Maybe Double`, use a conversion function:

```
rustToMaybe :: RustPtr a -> Maybe (Ptr a)
rustToMaybe (RustPtr p) | p == nullPtr = Nothing
                        | otherwise    = Just p
```

With inlining of `rustToMaybe`, the assembly generated for:

```
case rustToMaybe p of
    Nothing -> nothingBranch
    Just p' -> justBranch p'
```

will be free of any marshalling overhead.

You can also define a pattern synonym using view patterns to call the conversion function implicitly, which can be helpful if the Rust pointer is buried in some deeper pattern matching construct:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

pattern RustPtr' mp <- (rustToMaybe -> mp)
```

after which you can do things like:

```
case complexDataStructure of
    Thing (RustPtr' Nothing: rest) -> continueWith rest
    Thing (RustPtr' (Just p): _) -> useNonNullPtr p
```

Again, if the view function is inlined, there should be no marshalling overhead.

Working with a more typical tagged union return value would be similar.  Here, it might be a good idea to go through the usual process of making a marshallable data type.  If the C representation is:

```
typedef struct tagged_s {
        int tag;   /* 1 = double, 2 = int */
        union {
                double d;
                int i;
        };
} tagged_t;
```

then it can be marshalled into a GHC sum type with the usual alignment concerns as:

```
data Tagged = A Double | B Int

newtype C_Tagged = C_Tagged (Ptr Tagged)

instance Storable Tagged where
    peek p = do
      tag :: CInt <- peekByteOff p 0
      case tag of
        1 -> A <$> peekByteOff p 8
        2 -> B <$> peekByteOff p 8
```

Now, if you have some foreign functions that return tagged unions:

```
foreign import capi "tagged.c taggedDouble" taggedDouble :: IO C_Tagged
foreign import capi "tagged.c taggedInt" taggedInt :: IO C_Tagged
```

you can call them as usual:

```
td <- taggedDouble
ti <- taggedInt
```

and again, you can pass these `td` and `ti` objects around as-is with no marshalling.  When it comes time to case match on them, an unsafe view pattern synonym will do the trick:

```
pattern Tagged' t <- (\(C_Tagged p) -> unsafePerformIO (peek p) -> t)
```

and you can write code like:

```
main = do
    td <- taggedDouble
    ti <- taggedInt
    case (td, ti) of
        (Tagged' (A d), Tagged' (B i)) -> print d >> print i
        _ -> error "unexpected return values"
```

There's no sensible way to avoid `unsafePerformIO` here.  If you don't want to marshal the tagged union until the point of use in pure code (e.g., like a pattern match in a `case` statement), you have to make sure that the data structure can be accessed unsafely without issue.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. BTW, in the first approach, in the struct type definition, did you mean `void *payload[1];` instead of `[0]`? Later on you access `payload[0]` which is out-of-bounds (at least with that `malloc`).

Comment: Oops.  I intentionally wrote `payload[0]` as in a "variable length array at the end of a structure", but forgot about it when I wrote the `malloc`s.  I've fixed the `malloc`s now.